# How to add a merged shadow to expandable tableview cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, shadow, expandable-table

I have a tableview with expandable text cells, each cell has a white view with a shadow as background.

For the design, i want to merge cells shadow to be like the image :

[image]

So, i removed "Clip Subviews" check from cell.

But i had a problem with expanding animation, while animation the cells looks like this :

[image]

The animation problem fixed when i added again "Clip Subviews" check, but the shadow malformed and it's cropped.

Is there a way to keep shadow and right animation?